# What Happend In Akka-Http DSL?

Tags: scala, dsl, implicit-conversion, akka-http

I just touched akka recently, when learning akka-http, I am attracted by the Rest API DSL, here is a piece of code:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import scala.io.StdIn

object WebServer {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
      implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-system")
      implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
      // needed for the future flatMap/onComplete in the end
      implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher
      val route =
         path("hello") {
            get {
               complete("Say hello to akka-http")
            }
         }
      val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)
      println(s"Server online at http://localhost:8080/\nPress RETURN to stop...")
      StdIn.readLine() // let it run until user presses return
      bindingFuture
         .flatMap(_.unbind()) // trigger unbinding from the port
         .onComplete(_ => system.terminate()) // and shutdown when done
   }
}
```

What I cannot understand is the `val route = path("hello") {....}`. I know the “path” method will return a Directive, and the “get” method is also a Directive, but I can’t understand how can a directive “embeds” in another directive by the braces “{}”.

I know, there must be some implicit conversions, by debugging, I saw, the following implicit conversion is applied: `akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive#addByNameNullaryApply`

```
implicit def addByNameNullaryApply(directive: Directive0): (⇒ Route) ⇒ Route =
  r ⇒ directive.tapply(_ ⇒ r)
```

Can anybody explain to me: how can this implicit conversion is selected and happened?  And what dose the apply and tapply try to do? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First:

```
val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)
```

is equal to:

```
val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(Route.handlerFlow(route), "localhost", 8080)
```

the `Route.handlerFlow` method is used to conversion `Route` to `Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, NotUsed]`, as we see the `bindAndHandle` accept `handler` type is: `Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Any]`

the **implicit conversion** `route` to `Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, NotUsed]` is implemented by the `RouteResult.route2HandlerFlow`. and this is extended by `Directives` and work with `import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._`.

so when you **import Directives** , you import this **implicit conversions.**

**For `addByNameNullaryApply`**, we can rewrite code like the below:

```
...
val path1: Directive0 = path("hello")
val contextToEventualResult: Route = get(complete("Say hello to akka-http"))
val route: Route = path1.apply(contextToEventualResult)
...
```

as we can see, for `path1.apply(contextToEventualResult)` it's calling a **high-order function** with applying `contextToEventualResult` parameter. but for `path1`'s type is `Directive0`, so:

`implicit def addByNameNullaryApply(directive: Directive0): (⇒ Route) ⇒ Route` is used to convert the `Directive0` type to a **high order function** with type: `(⇒ Route) ⇒ Route`.

Comment: thanks for inputs, what i am really want to know is `val route = path("hello") {....}`, as i said in my post, it applied implicit conversion: addByNameNullaryApply, can you help explain this part?

Comment: @LaurenceGeng sorry misunderstand question, I have added *addByNameNullaryApply*  explanation, hopeful it's helpful for you.

Comment: Hi Chengpohi, the breakdown statments are more clear now, thanks. Can you explain the  `r`and `_` in `r ⇒ directive.tapply(_ ⇒ r)`?

Comment: @LaurenceGeng, it's a **high-order** function constructor, **r** mean the function parameter, **_** means any parameter(**wildcard**). see [Higher-order Functions](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/higher-order-functions.html). it's equal to `def f1(r: Route): Route = directive.tapply(_ ⇒ r)`.

Comment: Hi, @chengpohi, thanks for your warm help. i think i almost understand it. but here is a thing i am not clear about (⇒ Route) ⇒ Route, before, i think it's the same to (()⇒ Route) ⇒ Route, but it's not. I tested it as following: var hof: (=> Int) => Int = {r=>r+1}, then invoke it by hof({()=>1}), you know, it's wrong, if i change it to hof(1), if works, so, can you tell me what's meaning of (=>A-Certain-Type)? This maybe my last question~

Comment: @LaurenceGeng, I think you should open another question to ask this, it's more clear than ask in comments.